# What is the best practice of populating drop down fields based on api response in react

Tags: reactjs

```
    const comp=()=>{
    const [state,setState]=useState({data:[]});
    const coordinatorOptions=useMemo(()=>{getOptions(data,"Coordinator")}[data]);
    const severityOptions= useMemo(()=>{getOptions(data,"Severity")},[data]);
    const engagementOptions=useMemo(()=>{getOptions(data,"Engagement")},[data]);
     //
/// upto 8 dropdowns;
useEffect(()=>{
  setState({data})
},
[])
 return(
  <Dropdown options={coordinatorOptions or getOptions()}/>
  <Dropdown options={engagementOptions or getOptions()}/>
  <Dropdown options={severityOptions or getOptions()}/>
  // up to 8 drop downs
)
}
```

Which is the best practice to populate fields based on api response data. Is it good to use useMemo in case of lot of dropdowns or calling getOptions method in render is good?

Answer (score 0):

If it is used in many places, you can use save in a redux state else you can use  the useState to save the state.

Comment: My Question is, is the above usage of useMemo okay or should we have to useState instead of useMemo or call getOptionsMethod directly in render.